# How to resolve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, ssl, aws-lambda, apache-commons-io

I am trying to download a file from a url using Apache commons FileUtils on AWS Lambda.
But i am get this exception.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:994)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1478)
```

I have using java 8 in AWS Lambda.
I have tried

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
```

```
Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "");
```

```
public static void addSslToTrustStore() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        // Create all-trusting host name verifier
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting host verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    }
```

These were all the options I found online, but didn't worked for me.
File gets downloaded on my local with ou any exception but throws exception on lambda.
Please help me.

Comment: If the __remote__ host has closed the connection it does not help at at to disable __local__ certificate validation like you've tried. There can be many reasons for the servers behavior, like unsupported protocol versions or ciphers, requirement of client certificates, firewalls in between ... . It is impossible to say based on the currently provided details what happens here. A packet capture (with wireshark or similar) might provide details which help in debugging the problem as does enabling SSL local debugging or looking at server side logs.